# PHP Pthread Multithread code slower than single thread

Tags: php, arrays, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to do a very simple but numerous iterations task. I choose 7 random serial numbers from an array of 324000 serial numbers and place them in another array and then search that array to see if a particular number is within it, execute another script and fwrite out how many times the looked for number is in the array.

This goes fairly fast in single thread. But when I put it in pthreads, even one single pthread running is 100x slower than single thread. The workers are not sharing any resources (i.e. the grab all info from their own folders and write info to their own folders)..fwrite bottlenecks is not the problem. The problem is with the arrays which I note below. Am I running into a cache line problem, where the arrays although they have separate variables are still sharing the same cache line? Sigh...much appreciate your help, in figuring out why the arrays are slowing it to a crawl.

```
<?php

class WorkerThreads extends Thread
{
    private $workerId;
    private $linesId;
    private $linesId2;
    private $c2_result;
    private $traceId;

    public function __construct($id,$newlines,$newlines2,$xxtrace)
    {
        $this->workerId = $id;
        $this->linesId = (array) $newlines;
        $this->linesId2 = (array) $newlines2;
        $this->traceId = $xxtrace; 
        $this->c2_result= (array) array();
    }

    public function run()
    {
        for($h=0; $h<90; $h++) {
            $fp42=fopen("/folder/".$this->workerId."/count.txt","w");

            for($master=0; $master <200; $master++) {
                // *******PROBLEM IS IN THE <3000 loop -very slow***********
                $b=0;

                for($a=0; $a<3000; $a++) {
                    $zex=0;

                    while($zex != 1) {
                        $this->c2_result[0]=$this->linesId[rand(0,324631)];
                        $this->c2_result[1]=$this->linesId[rand(0,324631)];
                        $this->c2_result[2]=$this->linesId[rand(0,324631)];
                        $this->c2_result[3]=$this->linesId[rand(0,324631)];
                        $this->c2_result[4]=$this->linesId[rand(0,324631)];
                        $this->c2_result[5]=$this->linesId[rand(0,324631)];
                        $this->c2_result[6]=$this->linesId[rand(0,324631)];

                        if(count(array_flip($this->c2_result)) != count($this->c2_result)) { //echo "duplicates\n";
                            $zex=0;
                        } else { //echo "no duplicates\n";
                            $zex=1;
                            //exit;
                        }
                    }

                    // *********PROBLEM here too !in_array statement, slowing down******
                    if(!in_array($this->linesId2[$this->traceId],$this->c2_result)) {
                        //fwrite($fp4,"nothere\n");
                        $b++;
                    }
                }
                fwrite($fp42,$b."\n");
            }
            fclose($fp42);

            $mainfile3="/folder/".$this->workerId."/count_pthread.php";
            $command="php $mainfile3 $this->workerId";

            exec($command);
        }
    }
}

$xxTrack=0;

$lines = range(0, 324631);

for($x=0; $x<56; $x++) {
    $workers = [];

    // Initialize and start the threads
    foreach (range(0, 8) as $i) {
        $workers[$i] = new WorkerThreads($i,$lines,$lines2,$xxTrack);
        $workers[$i]->start();
        $xxTrack++;
    }

    // Let the threads come back
    foreach (range(0, 8) as $i) {
        $workers[$i]->join();
    }

    unset($workers);
}
```

**UPDATED CODE**

I was able to speed up the original code by 6x times with help from @tpunt suggestions. Most importantly what I learned is that the code is being slowed down by the calls to rand(). If I could get rid of that, then speed time would be 100x faster. array_rand,mt_rand() and shuffle() are even slower. Here is the new code:

```
 class WorkerThreads extends Thread
    {
        private $workerId;
        private $c2_result;
        private $traceId;
        private $myArray;
        private $myArray2;

        public function __construct($id,$xxtrace)
        {
            $this->workerId = $id;
            $this->traceId = $xxtrace; 
            $c2_result=array();
        }

        public function run()
        {
            ////////////////////THE WORK TO BE DONE/////////////////////////
            $lines = file("/fold/considers.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            $lines2= file("/fold/considers.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

            shuffle($lines2);

            $fp42=fopen("/fold/".$this->workerId."/count.txt","w");

            for($h=0; $h<90; $h++) {
                fseek($fp42, 0);

                for($master=0; $master <200; $master++) {
                    $b=0;

                    for($a=0; $a<3000; $a++) {
                        $zex=0;

                        $myArray = [];

$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;

while (count($myArray) !== 7) {
    $myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
}

if (!isset($myArray[$lines2[$this->traceId]])) {
    $b++;
}
                    }

                    fwrite($fp42,$b."\n");
                }

                $mainfile3="/newfolder/".$this->workerId."/pthread.php";
                $command="php $mainfile3 $this->workerId";

                exec($command);

            }//END OF H LOOP
            fclose($fp42);
        }
    }

    $xxTrack=0;
    $p = new Pool(5);


    for($b=0; $b<56; $b++) {
        $tasks[$b]= new WorkerThreads($b,$xxTrack);
        $xxTrack++;
    }

    // Add tasks to pool queue
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $p->submit($task);
    }

    // shutdown will wait for current queue to be completed
    $p->shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just incredibly inefficient. There are also a number of problems with it - I've made a quick breakdown of some of these things below.

Firstly, you are spinning up over 500 threads (9 * 56 = 504). This is going to be very slow because threading in PHP requires a shared-nothing architecture. This means that a new instance of PHP's interpreter will need to be created for each thread you create, where all classes, interfaces, traits, functions, etc, will need to be copied over to the new interpreter instance.

Perhaps more to the point, though, is that your 3 nested `for` loops are performing **54 million** iterations (90 * 200 * 3000). Multiply this by the 504 threads being created, and you can soon see why things are becoming sluggish. Instead, use a thread pool (see pthreads' `Pool` class) with a more modest amount of threads (try 8, and go from there), and cut down on the iterations being performed per thread.

Secondly, you are opening up a file 90 times per thread (so a total of 90 * 504 = 45360). You only need one file handler per thread.

Thirdly, utilising actual PHP arrays inside of `Threaded` objects makes them read-only. So with respect to the `$this->c2_result` property, the code inside of your nested `while` loop should not even work. Not to mention that the following check does not look for duplicates:

```
if(count(array_flip($this->c2_result)) != count($this->c2_result))
```

If you avoid casting the `$this->c2_result` property to an array (therefore making it a `Volatile` object), then the following code could instead replace your `while` loop:

```
$keys = array_rand($this->linesId, 7);
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; ++$i) {
    $this->c2_result[$this->linesId[$keys[$i]]] = true;
}
```

By setting the values as the keys in `$this->c2_result` we can remove the subsequent `in_array` function call to search through the `$this->c2_result`. This is done by utilising a PHP array as a hash table, where the lookup time for a key is constant time (O(1)), rather than linear time required when searching for values (with `in_array`). This enables us to replace the following slow check:

```
if(!in_array($this->linesId2[$this->traceId],$this->c2_result))
```

with the following fast check:

```
if (!isset($this->c2_result[$this->linesId2[$this->traceId]]))
```

But with that said, you don't seem to be using the `$this->c2_result` property anywhere else. So (assuming you haven't purposefully redacted code that uses it), you could remove it altogether and simply replace the while loop at check after it with the following:

```
$found = false;

foreach (array_rand($this->linesId, 7) as $key) {
    if ($this->linesId[$key] === $this->linesId2[$this->traceId]) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$found) {
    ++$b;
}
```

Beyond the above, you could also look at storing the data you're collecting in-memory (as some property on the `Threaded` object), to prevent expensive disk writes. The results could be aggregated at the end, before shutting down the pool.

**Update based up your update**

You've said that the `rand` function is causing major slowdown. Whilst it may be part of the problem, I believe it is actually all of the code inside of your third nested `for` loop. The code inside there is **very** hot code, because it gets executed 54 million times. I suggested above that you replace the following code:

```
$zex=0;

while($zex != 1) {
    $c2_result[0]=$lines[rand(0,324631)];
    $c2_result[1]=$lines[rand(0,324631)];
    $c2_result[2]=$lines[rand(0,324631)];
    $c2_result[3]=$lines[rand(0,324631)];
    $c2_result[4]=$lines[rand(0,324631)];
    $c2_result[5]=$lines[rand(0,324631)];
    $c2_result[6]=$lines[rand(0,324631)];

    $myArray = (array) $c2_result;
    $myArray2 = (array) $c2_result;
    $myArray=array_flip($myArray);

    if(count($myArray) != count($c2_result)) {//echo "duplicates\n";
        $zex=0;
    } else {//echo "no duplicates\n";
        $zex=1;
        //exit;
    }
}

if(!in_array($lines2[$this->traceId],$myArray2)) {
    $b++;
}
```

with a combination of `array_rand` and `foreach`. Upon some initial tests, it turns out that `array_rand` really is *outstandingly* slow. But my hash table solution to replace the `in_array` invocation still holds true. By leveraging a PHP array as a hash table (basically, store values as keys), we get a constant time lookup performance (O(1)), as opposed to a linear time lookup (O(n)).

Try replacing the above code with the following:

```
$myArray = [];

$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
$myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;

while (count($myArray) !== 7) {
    $myArray[rand(0,324631)] = true;
}

if (!isset($myArray[$lines2[$this->traceId]])) {
    $b++;
}
```

For me, this resulted in a 120% speedup.

As for further performance, you can (as mentioned above, again) store the results in-memory (as a simple property) and perform a write of all results at the end of the `run` method.

Also, the garbage collector for pthreads is not deterministic. It should therefore not be used to retrieve data. Instead, a `Threaded` object should be injected into the worker thread, where data to be collected should be saved to this object. Lastly, you should shutdown the pool *after* garbage collection (which, again, should not be used in your case).

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! I'm working through your suggestions...the only part I don't understand is that you indicate I have 500 worker threads running at the same time but I only see 9 working...doesn't the unset($workers) command, destroy the 9 workers every time I loop, and the  $workers = []; command, starts 9 new ones to replace the old?

Comment: @user3152377 You don't have 500 threads running *at the same time*, but you do create 500 threads. Specifically, your loop creates batches of 9 threads, 56 times. When you join the spawned threads, they are destroyed. If you utilised a thread pool instead, then you can simply create those 9 threads once, and reuse them for all 56 iterations of your outer loop.

Comment: Thanks for sorting me out! I posted the updated code, it is about 6-8x times faster. I kept the original code to insert random number in array because it was actually faster once I worked through all of the suggested replacements but I did delete all of those fwrites, put in a new pool instead of spinning up threads and destroying 500 times, fixed the non working duplicate test , and kept arrays as objects only casting at the end.  @tpunt

Comment: The rand() call is also a real problem, I tested the scripting and if I could get rid of rand(), It would be 100x faster. I tried array_rand, that was super slow...also, tried mt_rand and shuffle with array_slice. No cigar with any of those. Would you know of any speedier way to get a random number? @tpunt

Comment: @user3152377 I have updated my reply based upon your update (I've also placed your update on your original post, just to keep everything together).

Comment: Outstanding! New code did speed by >100%, code has been updated. I tested it for future portability, should I need to scale from 7 to 99 (max) later but for some reason it slowed after about 50, is there anyway to keep the speed up to 99? Also, I'll update code to add in the memory store and print of end results @tpunt

Comment: @user3152377 The only thing you can really do in this case is to decrease the iteration count of one of your `for` loops. Bloating the body of the inner-most `for` loop will drastically slow things down because that code is being executed 54 million times, so you really want it to be as lightweight as possible.

Comment: Thank you! @tpunt, It looks like it will workout on a scale up to 99 because I tested it with the addition of more workers and I got a good speed up to offset.

Answer (score 0):

despite it is unclear about your code and what $newlines and $newlines2 are, so, I am just guessing here...

something like this ?
The idea is to avoid as much as possible fopen and fwrite in your loop.
1 - open it only once in the construct.
2 - concat your chain in your loop.
3 - write it only once after the loop.

```
class WorkerThreads extends Thread {

private $workerId;
private $linesId;
private $linesId2;
private $c2_result;
private $traceId;
private $fp42;
private $mainfile3;

public function __construct($id, $newlines, $newlines2, $xxtrace) {
    $this->workerId = $id;
    $this->linesId = (array) $newlines;
    $this->linesId2 = (array) $newlines2;
    $this->traceId = $xxtrace;
    $this->c2_result = array();

    $this->fp42 = fopen("/folder/" . $id . "/count.txt", "w");
    $this->mainfile3 = "/folder/" . $id . "/count_pthread.php";
}

public function run() {
    for ($h = 0; $h < 90; $h++) {
        $globalf42='';
        for ($master = 0; $master < 200; $master++) {//<200
            $b = 0;
            for ($a = 0; $a < 3000; $a++) {
                $zex = 0;
                if ($zex != 1) {
                    for ($ii = 0; $ii < 6; $ii++) {
                        $this->c2_result[$ii] = $this->linesId[rand(0, 324631)];
                    }
                    $zex = (count(array_flip($this->c2_result)) != count($this->c2_result)) ? 0 : 1;
                }
                if (!in_array($this->linesId2[$this->traceId], $this->c2_result)) {
                    $b++;
                }
            }
            $globalf42 .= $b . "\n";
        }
        fwrite($this->fp42, $globalf42);
        fclose($this->fp42);
        $command = "php $this->mainfile3 $this->workerId";
        exec($command);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: $newlines and $newlines2 are both arrays, one array is the number that gets searched for and the other array is from which random pulls numbers from and puts into the 7 array data spots.  I'll try your suggestion and report...thanks! @cpugourou

Comment: Tried your code, unfortunately not a fwrite problem. It is an array problem in the 2 array areas that I indicated in my above code. Can you see anything in the array area (<3000) and in the (in_array search) that would be causing such a slow down? You can just reference the code you updated to....much appreciate it! @cpugourou

Comment: between the first loop (200) and the second one, do you absolutly need to keep up growing the array () ? try resetting $this->c2_result for each master loop.